# How can I split / trim Videos with Android SDK / NDK?

Tags: android

Is there a way to Split Videos with Android?

I want to give the user a chance to cut a video bevore uploading.

Best,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

How are you obtaining that videos in the first place? If using a library, the library itself may have the tools you need